# Sometimes Mongoose does not remove objects in time

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm using a pre-remove mongoose middleware to remove all the entries of a form before deleting it:

```
FormSchema.pre('remove', (next) ->
  tpEntryModel.removeQ({form: @_id}).then(next, next).done()
)
```

I have the following jasmine test for it:

```
  describe 'pre remove', () ->
    it 'should remove all entries for this form', (done) ->
      tpFormModel.createQ({})
      .then((form) ->
        tpEntryModel.createQ({form: form._id})
      ).then(() ->
        form.remove()
      ).then(() ->
        tpEntryModel.findQ({})
      ).then((entries) ->
        expect(entries.length).toBe(0)
        done()
      ).done()
```

Now this test usually passes, but sometimes it just fails , i.e. `entries.length` is 1 instead of 0.

*Any idea why this might happen?*

Notes:

- I drop the entire database before each test
- The promise syntax for mongoose is by [mongoose-q](https://github.com/iolo/mongoose-q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a mongoose specific problem. It has to do with what is called [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) in mongoland.

Here is what most likely happens in your case:

1. You use the default write concern, which is `acknowledged`
2. What happens when you delete the document is that the statement is accepted by the `mongod` instance, but not written to the data file or even the journal before your next read.
3. The document still exits, therefor your assertion fails.

The reason for the default write concern being `acknowledge` is that it is faster than waiting for the write operations to take place but still offers some possibilities to deal with errors (like network or connectivity errors).

A flush to the journal takes places every [commitIntervalMs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.journal.commitIntervalMs), while the datafile is updated from the journal every [syncPeriodSecs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs). There are a couple of reasons for that behavior, one of them being to prevent unnecessary relocations of a document in a datafile which is a *very* expensive operation.

So what you should do is to set the write concern for your tests to `j:true` or wait `commitIntervalMs` after the deletion of the document before doing your check.